# When will there be support for WYSIWIG editing of Silverlight XAML in Visual Studio?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Why do we have to spend more $$$ for Expression Blend after I already spent $$$$ for Visual Studio 2008 with MSDN subscription?  Will there be a service pack for 2008 to support this, will it be part of VS2010, or will we always have to use a separate tool?

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft has to fund Steve Ballmer's furniture budget from somewhere. Those chairs ain't free, y'know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you can do it [today](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx) (vs 2010 beta).  Is it a great idea?  I'm not sure.

It seems to me, there will always be room for a design tool for xaml.  With animations and brushes and everything else, it doesn't make sense to ball that all into VS.  My 2 cents.

HTH,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

I believe Microsoft is planning to keep this as a separate tool, and not include it (at least in the Pro level MSDN subscriptions).

The official thought seems to be Visual Studio->Programmer and Expression->Designer, and officially, the two programs are meant to be used by two separate people.  This gives them another revenue source, and a good enough excuse that I doubt they'll change it.

But... I don't work for Microsoft, and I won't pretend to understand the depth's of the craziness associated with Microsoft's development tools business model...